# How to store name value pair in Django db?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I want to create a student record data base using django db. The class will look something like below

```
class StudentRecord(models.Model): 
     studentname = models.CharField()
    #marks = ['Science':98, 'Maths':99, 'Computer'::95]
```

I want to add 'marks' field, which is like a dictionary or like a list of tuple. What is the best way to achieve this in Django ?
I am new to Django, and I could not find the relevant answer in the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/

Answer (score 2):

You usually work with an extra model. Since the subjects will likely be the same, even a third model:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)


class Mark(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    marks = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(100)]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want must be JSONField,this is the document:[JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield)

Comment: Please *don't*: relational databases are *not* good with composite fields. It will produce a database not in first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form and will not guarantee referential integrity for example.

Comment: may be you are right

Answer (score 1):

To store marks as a dictionary or a list of tuples in Django, you can use the JSONField or TextField field type.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class StudentRecord(models.Model): 
    studentname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    marks = JSONField(default=dict)
```

you can create by

```
record = StudentRecord.objects.create(studentname='John Doe', marks={'Science': 98, 'Maths': 99, 'Computer': 95})
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form